# Use time in dygraph range selector in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I need to build an app where time input in %T format has to modify time range visible on chart. I am using shiny and dygraph, and it works as stated in the documentation: one can extract dateWindow. However, changes in my system occur at a finer time scale, so I need to be able to control hours, minutes and seconds in the range selector. Is there any way to achieve that?

Here is an example: you can change the range with the dygraph range selector, and it shows hours and minutes, but when I press the button that reads the dygraph_date_window to a reactive value, only date is added. I am looking for a workaround, because I want to be able to update the time input field and (currently not in code) to update the range in the dygraph using the time input field.

```r
library(dygraphs)
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)

data("sample_matrix")
sample_xts<-as.xts(sample_matrix)


ui<-fluidPage(

      dygraphOutput("dygraph"),
      verbatimTextOutput("from"),
      dateInput("start_date","Start date"),
      timeInput("start_time","Start time"),
      actionButton("settime_bttn", "Set time")

)


server<-function(session, input, output) {


  #1. initialize time constraints
  timelimits<-reactiveValues(start=start(sample_xts),end=end(sample_xts))

  #2. draw dygraph with range selector
  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(sample_xts)%>% 
      dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c(timelimits$start,timelimits$end))

  })

  #3. modify timelimits and input fields with range selector
  observeEvent( input$settime_bttn, {
    rs<-input$dygraph_date_window
    timelimits$start<-rs[[1]]
    timelimits$end<-rs[[2]]
    updateDateInput(session, "start_date", value = substr(rs[[1]],1,10))
    updateTimeInput(session, "start_time", value = rs[[1]])
  })

  output$from <- renderText({
    req(input$dygraph_date_window[[1]])
  })

}

shiny::runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Hi, you should add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it is very hard to start from scratch and to reproduce your problem just with your explanations